# OffsetDateTime parsing

Tags: java, datetime

Need to parse Date time from format `2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680`.

First step using, tried to parse time without microseconds with line.

```
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

**Having exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2011-12-03T10:15:30' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2011-12-03T10:15:30 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at timeread.TimeReading.main(TimeReading.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2011-12-03T10:15:30 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:370)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneOffset from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2011-12-03T10:15:30 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.ZoneOffset.from(ZoneOffset.java:348)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:359)
    ... 9 more
```

Tried to use `DateTimeFormatter` with `TimeZone`

```
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

The similar **exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2011-12-03T10:15:30' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1322892930},ISO,Europe/Moscow resolved to 2011-12-03T10:15:30 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at timeread.TimeReading.main(TimeReading.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1322892930},ISO,Europe/Moscow resolved to 2011-12-03T10:15:30 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:370)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneOffset from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1322892930},ISO,Europe/Moscow resolved to 2011-12-03T10:15:30 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.ZoneOffset.from(ZoneOffset.java:348)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:359)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Welcome to Java.time-runtime-failures: Even the expression `OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))` produces the same exception (although here the missing zone offset is explicitly given as parameter to the formatter).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`OffsetDateTime.parse` requires a string containing an offset (`+/-hh:mm`), which `"2011-12-03T10:15:30"` doesn't have. Parse it with `LocalDateTime.parse` and convert the result using [`OffsetDateTime.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDateTime-java.time.ZoneOffset-).

Answer (score 24):

`OffsetDateTime` is a representation of a date-time with an
offset. 
To create a `OffsetDateTime`, you need an zone offset.

> A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar
>   system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00.

see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html

For example:

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

If you try to parse a date time with `ZoneId`, you should use `ZonedDateTime`.

> A date-time with a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as
>   2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 Europe/Paris.

see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html

For example:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2011-12-03T10:15:30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

If what you need is a datetime without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, you can use `LocalDateTime`.

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such
>   as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.

see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

For example:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly non-standard ISO(!) date to parse `2021-01-14T09:25:33+0000`

A standard `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` wouldn't handle it, but the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` can be used to create one that would, from an existing ISO Format.

```java
DateTimeFormatter customFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
   .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
   .appendOffset("+HHMM","Z")
   .toFormatter();
```

The important bit is the `.appendOffset()` method, as using `.ofPattern()` doesn't seem to work with Offset parsing.

Comment: Wikipedia says this is standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC

Comment: @ceving `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` expects a colon in the offset, which my date did not have.

Answer (score 0):

### `DateTimeFormatter` need not be specified to parse the given string

You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your date-time string, 2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680 into a `LocalDateTime` as it is already in the default format used by [`LocalDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). Note that `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680");
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680
```

### How to parse a `LocalDateTime` string into `OffsetDateTime`?

You can create a `DateTimeFormatter` with the applicable `ZoneId` to parse a `LocalDateTime` string into `ZonedDateTime` which can in turn be converted into an `OffsetDateTime`.

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680";

        // DateTimeFormatter with system time zone
        DateTimeFormatter parserForDefaultTz = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        OffsetDateTime odtSystemTz = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parserForDefaultTz).toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odtSystemTz);

        // DateTimeFormatter with UTC time zone offset
        DateTimeFormatter parserForUtc = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        OffsetDateTime odtUtc = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, parserForUtc).toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odtUtc);

        // For UTC it is even easier
        odtUtc = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        System.out.println(odtUtc);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680+01:00
2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680Z
2016-06-24T13:39:44.687680Z
```

However, a cleaner solution would be to parse a local date-time string into a `LocalDateTime` and convert it into an `OffsetDateTime` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66622113/10819573). Note that [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) is the default format used by `LocalDateTime#parse`. If your date-time string is in a custom format, create a corresponding `DateTimeFormatter` to use in this code.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.