# Threeten DateTimeParseException for OffsetDateTime.parse(String,dateTimeFormatter)

Tags: java, threetenbp

I would like to simply make a `DateTimeFormatter` to be used in `OffsetDateTime` parser. But I get `DateTimeParseException`:

```
final DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
ISO_LOCAL_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
    .appendLiteral('T')
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY,2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR,2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE,2)
    .toFormatter().withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT).withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE);

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
OffsetDateTime.parse("2012-03-06T00:00:00",ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

I looked into one similar issue but there was no clue there either :/
What is the problem with the code above? sth to do with `Formatter` or Threeten lib?

Comment: You should share your stacktraces

Comment: It seems you’re mimicing the predefined `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` and giving it the name `ISO_LOCAL_DATE`. That’s confusing. “Local” in `java.time` names means “without time zone or offset”, which may give you a hint.

Comment: Please, what would have been your desired result and why?

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298214/unable-to-obtain-offsetdatetime-from-temporalaccessor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OffsetDateTime parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048032/offsetdatetime-parsing)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify an offset in the input data.

This is an example of date-time with offset:

```
2012-03-06T00:00+01:00
```

Example of `ZonedDateTime`:

```
2012-03-06T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

`Europe/Berlin` - could be considered as `ZoneId` here. But each zone may have different offset for different time of the year (summer/winter time).

There is no one-to-one mapping between `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`:
[Is there any way to convert ZoneId to ZoneOffset in java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626733/is-there-any-way-to-convert-zoneid-to-zoneoffset-in-java-8)

Instead of specifying `ZoneOffset` you can specify `ZoneId` and the offset will be determined automatically.

Then you can get `ZonedDateTime` and convert it to `OffsetDateTime`.

> ```
> public OffsetDateTime ZonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime()
> ```
>
> This creates an offset date-time using the local date-time and offset.
>   The zone ID is ignored.

A fix for your case specifying `ZoneId`:

```
public class Main {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY,2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR,2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE,2)
            .toFormatter()
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
            .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE)
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()); // or whatever you have

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2012-03-06T00:00:00", ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime());
    }
}
```

Approximate output:

```
2012-03-06T00:00+01:00[Europe/City]
2012-03-06T00:00+01:00
```

Second option to fix - add `offsetId()` to your parser builder and specify offset part for the input string:

```
public class Main {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY,2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR,2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE,2)
            .appendOffsetId()
            .toFormatter()
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
            .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2012-03-06T00:00:00+02:00", ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        System.out.println(offsetDateTime);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2012-03-06T00:00+02:00
```

You can specify your own offset pattern instead of `.appendOffsetId()` like:

```
.appendOffset("+HH:mm", "Z")
```

By the way, there are bunch of standard `DateTimeFormatter`s you can use out-of-the-box to parse `OffsetDateTime`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String offsetStringTime = "2012-03-06T00:00:00+02:00";
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(offsetStringTime);
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime2 = OffsetDateTime.parse(offsetStringTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime3 = OffsetDateTime.parse(offsetStringTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(offsetDateTime);
        System.out.println(offsetDateTime2);
        System.out.println(offsetDateTime3);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2012-03-06T00:00+02:00
2012-03-06T00:00+02:00
2012-03-06T00:00+02:00
```

Comment: Excellent! You're right. But what I actually need is a valid formatter to be used for an OffsetDateTime parser which is out of my reach and I can only set a formatter for it. Is it possible to get a formatter from ZonedDateTime?! Since the ISO_LOCAL_DATE is not valid for OffsetDateTime parser.

Comment: @user737862 Added an example, please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: @user737862 I may be repeating what is already in the edited answer, but just set the formatter to `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`. There’s no reason build your own formatter for it.