# How to convert LocalDateTime to OffsetDateTime?

Tags: java-8, date-conversion, localdatetime, offsetdatetime

How to convert `LocalDateTime` to `OffsetDateTime`?

```
private OffsetDateTime getEntryDate(Payment payment) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(payment)
                   .map(Payment::getEntryDate)
                   .map(SHOULD RETURN OffsetDateTime)
                   .orElse(null);
}
```

`Payment::getEntryDate` will return `LocalDateTime`

Comment: `OffsetDataTime::of(LocalDataTime, ZoneOffset)`?

Comment: How to get that ZoneOffset ?

Comment: from where? it is up to you to know it

Comment: I mean a `LocalDataTime` is exactly that, a *Local*... whatever the offset you want to apply is up to you, there are some predefined types, the most common `UTC` I guess

Comment: I need to keep all the information, so i cant guess what ZoneOffset  to use.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to obtain the ZoneOffset to use when creating your OffsetDateTime. One approach is to use a ZoneId for your location:

```
final ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
ZoneOffset zoneOffSet = zone.getRules().getOffset(localDateTime);
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = localDateTime.atOffset(zoneOffSet);
System.out.println(offsetDateTime); // 2019-08-08T09:54:10.761+02:00
```

Answer (score 34):

There are many ways to convert `LocalDateTime` to `OffsetDateTime`. Some of them are listed below:

**1. Using [`LocalDateTime#atOffset​(ZoneOffset offset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atOffset(java.time.ZoneOffset)):**

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset(offset);
```

**2. Using [`LocalDateTime#atZone​(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone(java.time.ZoneId)) => [`ZonedDateTime#toOffsetDateTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toOffsetDateTime()):**

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();

// Change the ZoneId as required e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atZone(zoneId).toOffsetDateTime();
```

**3. Using [`OffsetDateTime#of​(LocalDateTime dateTime, ZoneOffset offset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#of(java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.ZoneOffset)):**

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(ldt, offset);
```

**4. [`ZonedDateTime#of​(LocalDateTime localDateTime, ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of(java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.ZoneId)) => `ZonedDateTime#toOffsetDateTime()`:**

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();

// Change the ZoneId as required e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

OffsetDateTime odt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, zoneId).toOffsetDateTime();
```

---

**Notes:**

1. In all the solutions given above, replace the sample `ZoneOffset` as required e.g. `ZoneOffset offset =  ZoneOffset.of("+02:00")`.
2. In all the solutions given above, replace the sample `LocalDateTime` as required e.g. `LocalDateTime ldt =  LocalDateTime.of(2021, 3, 14, 10, 20)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 OffsetDateTime convertToOffsetDateTime(LocalDateTime ldt) {
        ZoneOffset offset = OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset();
        OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = ldt.atOffset(offset);
        return offsetDateTime;
    }
```

Comment: explain it in detail

Comment: You give a LocalDateTime object and create a offset on your localmaschine. Then you create an offsetDateTime with this offset and return it.
The original Offset ist lost anyway because LocalDateTime don't store it, so we have to create it

Comment: if you want the offset of the jvm default timezone, you can write it in a single line : `ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime()`

Answer (score 0):

An OffsetDateTime is just a date time with an offset from UTC.

So if you have a fixed offset (e.g. +02 from UTC), you can convert the localDateTime like this :

```
OffsetDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneOffset.of("+2"));
OffsetDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneOffset.of("+02"));
OffsetDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));
```

Most of the time you want to have the offset of a specific timezone, in this case it would be preferable to use a `ZonedDateTime` because for most timezone the offset is not the same in summer/winter and `ZonedDateTime` will automatically handle it for you.

If you absolutely want an `OffsetDateTime` with an offset from a specific timezone, you can write :

```
localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).toOffsetDateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
public Instant toInstant(LocalDate date) {
    return date
        .atStartOfDay()
        .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
}

public OffsetDateTime toOffsetDateTime(LocalDate date) {
    return OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(
        toInstant(date),
        ZoneOffset.UTC
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a specific LocalDateTime to an OffsetDateTime this might help you:

```
final LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("localDateTime = " + localDateTime);

final ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(3);
final OffsetDateTime offsetDateTimeRef = OffsetDateTime.now(offset);
System.out.println("offsetDateTimeRef = " + offsetDateTimeRef);

final OffsetDateTime offsetDateTimeFromLocalDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(localDateTime)), offset);
System.out.println("offsetDateTimeFromLocalDateTime = " + offsetDateTimeFromLocalDateTime);
```

Output:

```
localDateTime                   = 2022-11-11T23:58:34.260550200
offsetDateTimeRef               = 2022-11-12T01:58:34.262501700+03:00
offsetDateTimeFromLocalDateTime = 2022-11-12T01:58:34.260550200+03:00
```