# OffsetDateTime invalid format

Tags: java, jackson

I try to take a string who contain a vlaue of zoneDateTime.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
String date = "2019-06-12T22:00:00-04:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = objectMapper.readValue(date, OffsetDateTime.class);
System.out.println(odt);
```

Jackson said: parserException: unexpected character -

This command is valid

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-06-12T22:00:00-04:00");
```

So seem like a jackson issue

Comment: From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38048393/11023871), I guess your problem is that you use the character '-' in your `date` string. Your hour and minute should be separated by ':'

Comment: time in the string: 22:00:00

Comment: @DavidBuzatu It is an offset date time string. That means the `-04:00` is the offset from UTC.

Answer (score 1):

The `objectMapper.readValue(date, OffsetDateTime.class)` expects the string `date` to be valid JSON.

So, one way to use this would be to start with an example such as the following:

```
String json = "{ \"odt\" : \"2019-06-12T22:00:00-04:00\" }";
```

And then create an object to store this JSON, for example:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class ODT {

    private OffsetDateTime odt;

    public OffsetDateTime getOdt() {
        return odt;
    }

    public void setOdt(OffsetDateTime odt) {
        this.odt = odt;
    }
    
}
```

Now, the following code will handle the input successfully, using your object mapper:

```
ODT myOdt = objectMapper.readValue(json, ODT.class);
System.out.println(myOdt.getOdt());
```

This prints:

```
2019-06-13T02:00Z
```

**Update**

To display this value using the original offset, instead of UTC, you can use the following:

```
System.out.println(myOdt.getOdt().atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("-04:00")));
```

This prints:

```
2019-06-12T22:00-04:00
```

This is the same as the original value in our starting JSON string.

Comment: Locally, I have new york time. zone.. so -4  i was expected to get 2019-06-12T18:00

Comment: Understood - I have updated my answer to cover your point (but it should be 22:00 not 18:00, right?). Since the original time was 22:00 in the -04:00 offset, that would be 02:00 the next day in UTC time (as shown in my initial answer). So, re-adjusting the display string for this offset takes us back to the starting time. Hope that makes sense.